# Define a computed column in view as not null

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a view with computed columns now I need to enforce the computed columns to be "`not null`" for lightswitch.

I tried to `cast()` but I still cant get the computed columns to be "`not null`"
Is it possible?

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT dbo.Nop_Manufacturer.Name,
       CAST(SUM(dbo.Nop_OrderProductVariant.PriceExclTax) AS INT)           AS
       SALES,
       CAST(MONTH(dbo.Nop_Order.PaidDate) AS INT)                           AS
       paid_month,
       CAST(YEAR(dbo.Nop_Order.PaidDate) AS INT)                            AS
       paid_year,
       CAST(COUNT(dbo.Nop_OrderProductVariant.OrderProductVariantID) AS INT)AS
       num_prod_sold
FROM   dbo.Nop_ProductVariant
       INNER JOIN dbo.Nop_OrderProductVariant
         ON dbo.Nop_ProductVariant.ProductVariantId =
            dbo.Nop_OrderProductVariant.ProductVariantID
       INNER JOIN dbo.Nop_Product
         ON dbo.Nop_ProductVariant.ProductID = dbo.Nop_Product.ProductId
       INNER JOIN dbo.Nop_Product_Manufacturer_Mapping
                  INNER JOIN dbo.Nop_Manufacturer
                    ON dbo.Nop_Product_Manufacturer_Mapping.ManufacturerID =
                       dbo.Nop_Manufacturer.ManufacturerID
         ON dbo.Nop_Product.ProductId =
            dbo.Nop_Product_Manufacturer_Mapping.ProductID
       INNER JOIN dbo.Nop_Order
         ON dbo.Nop_OrderProductVariant.OrderID = dbo.Nop_Order.OrderID
WHERE  ( NOT ( dbo.Nop_Order.PaidDate IS NULL ) )
GROUP  BY dbo.Nop_Manufacturer.Name,
          MONTH(dbo.Nop_Order.PaidDate),
          YEAR(dbo.Nop_Order.PaidDate)
```

Answer (score 3):

`CAST`-ing as `INT` won't do anything to affect the perceived nullability of computed columns. You need to wrap them in `ISNULL` instead.

e.g. `ISNULL(YEAR(dbo.Nop_Order.PaidDate),0)`

This is documented in the [last paragraph here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx)

> The Database Engine automatically determines the nullability of
>   computed columns based on the expressions used. The result of most
>   expressions is considered nullable even if only nonnullable columns
>   are present, because possible underflows or overflows will produce
>   null results as well. Use the `COLUMNPROPERTY` function with the
>   `AllowsNull` property to investigate the nullability of any computed
>   column in a table. An expression that is nullable can be turned into a
>   nonnullable one by specifying `ISNULL(check_expression, constant)`,
>   where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any null result.

Comment: very good, I was struggling for the same thing. I was using COALESCE, my favorite, but only ISNULL sets the column to NOT NULL, at least in a table. thanks for sharing.